# CAS authentication against database using a md5 crypt() password

Tags: cas

I would like to know what parameters I have to specify when using CAS to authenticate using a Database (MySQL) with passwords encrypted using the Crypt() function. In my case I basically use MD5 but with salt, so I don't know where to precise this thing. Thanks ;)

I currently have those parameters :

```
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].passwordEncoder.type=DEFAULT
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].passwordEncoder.encodingAlgorithm=MD5
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].passwordEncoder.characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].passwordEncoder.type=GLIBC_CRYPT